# Laravel Auth Middleware on api.php causes Unauthenticated in the console and 401 error

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I want to add a  `middleware('auth');` for my `Route::post('/addUserJob', 'UserJobController@create');`.

This route is registered in `api.php` and is called in one of my .vue file
`axios.post('api/addUserJob',{id: 1})`

The problem is adding the middleware in the route by

`Route::post('/addUserJob', 'UserJobController@create')->middlware('auth');` causes **unauthenticated** message in the console and a **401**

```
class UserJobController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    
    public function create() {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

Comment: Howdy,  the /api endpoints should use the auth:api middleware.  I suggest installing passport in order to consume your own api via your app with axios.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport    /api routes are stateless so they don't have access to your cookies and session data.  Passport gives you helpers to axios.   Alternatively, move the route to web.php with standard auth middleware and use $user = Auth::user();    return response()->json($user);

Answer (score 0):

`__contruct` isn't `__construct`. No, your middleware you defined in the constructor is never ran because you didn't define a constructor.

Comment: oh. right. so stupid of me. now both of procedures experience the same error. Thanks! 

PS: edited the question